# JDO Query Performance and Transaction

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, transactions, jdo

Trying to optimise one of a big query in our GAE/J datastore, and during the experiment found some results which were not expected.

The code itself is pretty straightforward, which I copied below:

```
public static CursorEntityWrapper<Media> getMediasByUsernameCursored(String username, String cursorString, int batchSize, MediaFetchGroup... fetchGroups) {

    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    List<Media> result = new ArrayList<>();
    Transaction tx = pm.currentTransaction();
    try {
        DBUtils.applyFetchGroups(pm, fetchGroups);
        tx.begin();
        Query query = pm.newQuery(Media.class);
        query.getFetchPlan().setFetchSize(batchSize);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(cursorString)) {
            Cursor c = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            Map<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<>();
            extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, c);
            query.setExtensions(extensionMap);
        }

        query.setFilter("mediaUserString == userParam");
        query.declareParameters("java.lang.String userParam");
        query.setRange(0, batchSize);
        result = (List<Media>) query.execute(username);
        Cursor cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(result);
        cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();
        tx.commit();

    } finally {
        DBUtils.closeTransaction(tx, log);
        DBUtils.closePMAndDetachResult(pm, result);
    }
    return results;}
```

As you can see, we have a query method to return all entity Media by username. This entity has some child entities you can pass in as optional parameters.

We got a very poor performance for this query when asking for one of the large fetchgroups. For 60 entities result, it takes about 10 - 15 seconds to return, and when the result is at 200 size, the response can take up to 40 seconds.

One of the interesting experiment was we thought the transaction should have a major impact on the performance, so we take off the transaction from the method, and deployed the application again. But it seems we are wrong that the method became even slower when transaction was not presented.

So my question is why a query without transaction will be slower than with transaction?

Comment: perhaps looking in the log would tell you why, since it has times for all operations ...

Comment: Please share the observations from your optimization trials. Are you sure these numbers are not for the first, ie., the loading request which is supposed to take a long time?

Comment: @NeilStockton That's the first thing comes to my mind. I have tried using AppStats to see what exactly is happening. But again, there is not a lot I can tell since this is basically just a single query.

Comment: @user87049 Yes, I made sure I had run the tests for about 10 times, and it's not a first request of a fresh instance.